# How to install Virtual PC 2007 on Windows 7 Enterprise Edition 64 bit?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, virtual-machines, windows-virtual-pc

How to install Virtual PC 2007 on Windows 7 Enterprise Edition 64 bit?
When I tried to install it, Windows complained about compatibility issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't install it. You should install the new [Windows Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx).

Comment: Thank you but if i use Windows Virtual PC I cannot create Windows Server 2003 compatibility version ???

Comment: You can. It's not officially supported, but Windows Server 2003 runs perfectly fine in Windows Virtual PC.

Comment: can u give me few pointers to create VM for windows server 2003 plz

Comment: Just create the VM as usual and use a Windows Server 2003 CD-ROM (or ISO image) to install it. There really isn't any difference than installing Windows XP.